# Google Fusion Tables : when filtering a text column, how to ask "contains A" AND "contains B" (ditto for OR and NOT)?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Beginner's question : I am creating a Fusion Table with one of the columns being a column of tags, e.g. :

1. New York, London, Paris
2. Berlin, Tokyo
3. New York, Tokyo
4. Paris, Rome, Tokyo
5. Paris, Berlin, London

The Filter dropdown (blue) provides me with checkboxes for the 5 above examples, but allows me also to enter a specific text as a query. How must I proceed to enter the equivalent of :

- Paris AND London (results 1 and 5)
- Berlin OR Tokyo (results 2, 3, 4 and 5)
- Paris NOT New York (results 4 and 5)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WHERE  IN ('New York', 'London', 'Paris')

Your IN (xxx,xxx,xxx) will depend on list of cities. The IN operator implies an OR condition.
Not sure how an AND condition would work in your case.  See: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#Select and search for <column_condition>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution should work inside a query (I looked into the SQL reference), but not inside Google Drive itself : I want to use Fusion Tables as I would use Docs or Spreadsheets. I found out that the "classic look" offers better filtering capacities than the "new look", albeit limited to AND (no NOT nor OR) : I suppose I shall have to accept this. And I do not think it is possible to edit the filter formula (right of the blue filter button) in the "new look". Thanks again, anyhow.